# Proving: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1/(1+t^2)^2dt = \pi / 2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Prove that: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {(1+t^2)^2}dt = \frac \pi 2$

My approach: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {(1+t^2)^2}dt = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-R}^R \frac 1 {(1+t^2)^2}dt$

The function has two poles: $\pm i$

Now look at the path $\gamma$ starting at $-R$, going to $R$ and then going back to $-R$ as a halfcircle with a radius big enough that $i$ is inside the halfcircle. Then we have $$n(\gamma, i)=1, \,\,n(\gamma, -i)=0$$ We have:
$$\int_{-R}^R \frac 1 {(1+t^2)^2}dt = \int_\gamma f(z)dz - \int_{\text{Halfcircle}}f(z)dz$$ where $f$ is our function. We apply the residue theorem to the first integral and obtain it's value to be: $$res_i(f)$$.

I don't know how to calculate this residuum now though. I tried to apply a lemma from the lecutre which yields: ${\rm res}_i(f) = \lim_{z \rightarrow i}(z-i) f(z)$. But this evaluates to $\lim_{z \rightarrow i} \frac 1 {z^3+iz^2+z+i} = \infty$

So how to calculate the residuum?

And, how to calculate $\int_{\text{Halfcircle}}f(z)dz$? I think it should be $0$ for $R\rightarrow\infty$ because there was a similar example in the lecture where the prof just said it's $0$ without explaining why.

Comment: Did you parameterize the integral? That is, let $z = Re^{it}.$

Comment: Might help to note that $$\int\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}=\frac12\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}+\frac12\arctan x$$
But you can do it with residues as well, of course.